# Include a XML in XSLT and then apply a foreach

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a website coded with XML+XSLT that outputs me a full HTML website. Now, to make the site more dinamic I want to split some parts of the document: the header, footer and sidebar. I was looking at Google and I found this solution:

```
<xsl:param name="doc" select="document('menu.xml')"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html><head></head><body><xsl:for-each
select="$doc"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:for-each></body></html>
</xsl:template>
```

I was trying to apply it and I can get it working. This is the way I am using:

I changed the route to "../menu.xml" becasuse the xsl is inside a folder, this works well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="menu" select="document('../menu.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
```

more valid and working code and then:

```
<ul class="menu_top">
    <xsl:for-each select="$menu">
        <li>
            <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    #<xsl:value-of select="link" />
                </xsl:attribute>

                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
<xsl:for-each select="$menu">
    <div class="submenu"> 
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="link" />
        </xsl:attribute>

        <ul>
            <xsl:for-each select="child">
                <li>
                    <a>
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                            <xsl:value-of select="link" />
                        </xsl:attribute>

                        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Finally my menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu>
        <category>
            <name>First</name>
            <link>menu-1</link>

            <child>
                <name>Child 1</name>
                <link>#</link>
            </child>

            <child>
                <name>Child 2</name>
                <link>#</link>
            </child>          
        </category>
</menu>
```

I've more categories entries but I simplified it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `document()` function returns the root of the document you're importing. In this case, that's the `menu` element, not the `category` element. If you want to loop through the categories, use this instead:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$menu/menu/category">
   ...
```

Comment: Thank you Welbog! This works fine. I tried to vote up but I've no enough reputation! Thanks another time! :)

Comment: @Isern Palaus: Also, there is no need for all those `for-each`. It is prefectly valid `apply-templates select="$doc"`. Check my XML/XSLT Client Side site at http://www.aranedabienesraices.com.ar

Comment: @Isern Palaus: Then ask a question with inputs sample and desired output.